# Trying to add locales to a Flex mobile app: resourceManager is null

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6, flex-mobile, flex4.7

In Flash Builder 4.7 (with AIR 3.5) I'm trying to add locales en_US and de_DE to a Flex Mobile app, which originally has been ru_RU only.

I.e. originally I only had `-locale ru_RU` in Project Properties -> Flex compiler and hardcoded russian text in the source code (everything worked ok).

But after studying the [Adobe docs Localization in Flex – Part 1: Compiling resources into an application](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_localization_pt1.html) and [Adding new locales](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f2d.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f34) I have changed the Flex compiler (flags) to: `-locale ru_RU en_US de_DE`:

[image]

And have added `src\locale\{locale}` to the Source Path:

[image]

Finally I have created the subdirs and files

```
src\locale\ru_RU\resources.properties
src\locale\en_US\resources.properties
src\locale\de_DE\resources.properties
```

Here the en_US\resources.properties contents:

```
menu.play=Play via
menu.weekly=Weekly rating
menu.daily=Daily misere
menu.settings=Settings
```

The AIR 3.5 SDK dir already contains the 3 subdirs per se:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0 (AIR 3.5)\

frameworks\projects\framework\bundles\ru_RU
frameworks\projects\framework\bundles\en_US
frameworks\projects\framework\bundles\de_DE
```

so I haven't used the `copylocale` utility (right?)

In my source code I have change the first View:

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [ResourceBundle("resources")]
</fx:Metadata> 
......

[Bindable]
private var _ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    { icon: OK_ICON, view: OK, label: resourceManager.getString('resources','menu.play'), msg: 'Odnoklassniki.ru' },
    { icon: MR_ICON, view: MR, label: resourceManager.getString('resources','menu.play'), msg: 'Mail.ru' },
    { icon: VK_ICON, view: VK, label: resourceManager.getString('resources','menu.play'), msg: 'Vk.com' },
    { icon: FB_ICON, view: FB, label: resourceManager.getString('resources','menu.play'), msg: 'Facebook.com' },
    { icon: GG_ICON, view: GG, label: resourceManager.getString('resources','menu.play'), msg: 'Google+' }
]);
```

However that new code bombs out at the runtime, saying that the `resourceManager` is null.

What have I missed please?

Should I initialize the `resourceManager` somehow?

Comment: Not sure if this was an issue for you, but I found that without defining the compiler argument as `-locale=en_US,ru_RU` the compiler would not recognize the multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it seems to make sense:

You're trying to use the `ResourceManager` when initializing the `ArrayCollection`.  This sort of variable initialization happens when the class is created, and it's very likely that is not enough time for Flex to do all the things it does w/your view (like initialize it's `resourceManager` property).

If you populate your `ArrayCollection` after the view dispatches a "creationComplete" event, then you should be guaranteed that the `resourceManager` is no longer null. Perhaps you can try some of the other Flex life cycle events that get dispatched before "creationComplete" like "initialize" to do this work a bit sooner...

Comment: That was it, thank you! Moved it to `initialize` stage and now it works. Do I have to update `_ac` manually, when changing locale? I've added a button with `click="resourceManager.localeChain=['de_DE']"` but the `_ac` and the List using it do not update by themselves.

Comment: "Normally", you shouldn't have to do that... It's been too long since I did this, so this may not be correct. I put "normal" in quotes because the simple use case is something like this:  `<s:Label text={resourceManager.getString(....)} />` By binding like this, I believe the resourceManager will dispatch an event to trigger another call to get the string when the language changes. However, in your case the elements of your `ArrayCollection` are just objects (not `EventDispatcher`'s), so the elements in your dataProvider are not listening for binding events and won't know the lang has changed.

Comment: You could refactor your list so that the dataProvider contains the resource bundle ID for the string, rather then the string itself.  Then in the item renderer, use a binding expression as in my comment above to populate the label in the renderer w/the appropriate string. I'm not sure if this has any performance implications (may impact scrolling performance of the list).

Answer (score 0):

your missing the comma in your compiler argument between the locale codes.

if you want to put your locals under your src folder like i do you can add the following compiler arguments.

```
-locale=en_US,fr_FR,zh_CN,pt_BR -allow-source-path-overlap=true -source-path=locale/{locale}
```